# How can I create daily Pentaho reports automatically?

Tags: sql, report, pentaho, business-intelligence, data-integration

I want to create a report with Pentaho everyday without doing it manually. The report should integrate data from a SQL database. How I´m supposed to do that?

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: I tried to do it with the BI-Server of Pentaho, but it was not what I´ve expected.

Answer (score 0):

When you've created the report, upload it to the server and then on the server select the report and create a schedule with the desired parameters.

Comment: Ok and how I upload a report to the server? And how can I create a new schedule? There is no button to do that. Sorry, but I´m new in using Pentaho. It would be nice, if you could send a link to a guide or something. :D

Comment: The report is a new one everyday and when I upload it to the server, it wouldn´t have dynamic data from a sql database or am I wrong?

Comment: *question of me xD    I made it with your help, but another problem is that the reports are going to be saved anywhere I don´t know. Do I really have to download the report from the server to have it saved local? Is there any way to do it automatically?